# How do I speed up lmfit as much as possible?

Tags: python, performance, lmfit

I'm using lmfit to fit a skewed gaussian function to a large number of individual dataset (10 000). I get very good results but the time it takes to fit 10 000 pixels is quite long so every milisecond I can shave of the fit time would be helpful. This is the code I'm using where x and y is the data I want to fit. The guesses of parameters are working really well for me but were produced mostly through trial and error.

```py
import lmfit as lm
from lmfit import Model
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, ConstantModel, ExponentialGaussianModel, SkewedGaussianModel
from lmfit import Parameters

def LM_skewedgauss(x,y):
    supermodel = ConstantModel() + SkewedGaussianModel()
    x = x
    
    # Guesses
    
    a_peak = np.max(y)
    #16 is a needed constant from the way the data is produced
    t_peak = np.where(y == a_peak)[0][0]*16 
    avg = np.mean(y)
    gamma = 1.5
    sigma = 31

    params = supermodel.make_params(amplitude = a_peak*sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi),
                                    center = t_peak,
                                    sigma = sigma,
                                    gamma = gamma,
                                    c = 3)
    result = supermodel.fit(counts, params = params, x = x)
    #result.plot()

    bestparam = result.params
```

Answer (score 0):

As with Python itself, `lmfit` is designed to optimize developer (or probably more often "scientist") time.  With that view in mind, getting a 10x speedup of 10,000 fits is then actually pretty simple (and inexpensive):  Get a machine with 10+ cores (or compute threads), and split the problem into 10 scripts doing 1,000 fits each.